# How to improve Arduino Due timer precision?

Tags: timer, arduino, interrupt

I am using Due's timer interrupt to call a routine periodically, the code fragment is bellow. I use "ticks" variable to calculate timer's period to call a routine. The code is working very well, the problem is that it isn't very precise.
For example if I set period to 200 milliseconds, I get 193.7, it is worse for smallest periods, if I set 10 milliseconds I get only 5.6. I need microseconds precision in my code.
I tried all the timers divisors, currently I am using 128, and all the nine timers and the problem persist. Anyone can say why this is so imprecise and how to improve it?
Thanks in advance.

```
pmc_set_writeprotect(false);         // disable write protection for pmc registers
pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_TC7);   // enable peripheral clock TC7

TC_Configure(TC2,1, TC_CMR_WAVE | TC_CMR_WAVSEL_UP_RC | TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK4); //Division by 128
TC_SetRC(TC2, 1, ticks); //ticks = (84MHz/128) * period
TC_Start(TC2, 1);

// enable timer interrupts on the timer
TC2->TC_CHANNEL[1].TC_IER=TC_IER_CPCS;   // IER = interrupt enable register
TC2->TC_CHANNEL[1].TC_IDR=~TC_IER_CPCS;  // IDR = interrupt disable register

/* Enable the interrupt in the nested vector interrupt controller */
NVIC_EnableIRQ(TC7_IRQn);
```

Comment: Just a question: you are using a 200 MILLIseconds delay and you want it to be precise up to one MICROsecond, right? If so then... Well, you have to add your own temperature compensated oscillator because I don't think there are the precision oscillator specs, but usually it is around 10ppm (which means 2 microseconds on a 200 milliseconds delay)

Comment: Sorry... there was the part number on the schematic. It's precision is 30ppm, so even worse than what I thought...

Comment: Until 20 microseconds of precision is sufficient to do what I need. The problem is that the error is about 5 milliseconds for small periods, I have more than 50% of error when I set 10 milliseconds period.

Answer (score 0):

For the most accurate timing, you should be using the 12 MHz external crystal for the main clock. The internal RC clock is not as accurate.

But the problem you are having looks like it could arise from integer division. What is the exact expression you use to calculate `ticks`? Is there some undesired truncation going on?

Comment: ticks = period * 84000000/128.0; where period is float type.     The problem is that the error increase as that period decrease. I plotted the error in function to period and the function is quadratic. It does not make sense.

Comment: @EdsonRodrigues I suggest you try using integer arithmetic. As it happens, 84000000 is a multiple of 128, so `uint32_t ticks = 84000000 / 128 * (uint32_t)(period + 0.5);` should work. While we are on the subject, why is period a float? Is there some truncation going on in its calculation? Maybe try making period and integer type, too.